# Forming basis in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for some help with the following question. For which value or values of $k$ do the vectors below form a basis of $ \Bbb R^4$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&2  
\\0&1&0&3   
\\0&0&1&4
\\2&3&4&k
\end{bmatrix}$

My thinking is that the columns of this matrix are linearly independent if and only if the matrix is invertible If and only if the determinant of the matrix $\ne0$

So looking for some help with this question.  Would I have to calculate the determinant of this matrix to see what values of $k$ would form a basis of $ \Bbb R^4$. And if so wouldn't there be more than one possible value of $k$ that would make this true? Looking for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&2  
\\0&1&0&3   
\\0&0&1&4
\\2&3&4&k
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&2  
\\0&1&0&3   
\\0&0&1&4
\\0&3&4&k-2(2)
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&2  
\\0&1&0&3   
\\0&0&1&4
\\0&0&4&k-2(2)-3(3)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Are you able to finish the working?

Comment: are you bringing this to row echelon form?

Comment: yup, the intention is actually adding a multiple of a row to another row doesn't change the determinant.

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh would this give us $ k \ne 23 $ or $ k \ne 29$ ? thanks for your help

Comment: If you proceed on with the working, you should find that determinant is $k-29$. Hence for it to be non-zero, $k \neq 29$.

Comment: $2(2)+3(3)+4(4)=29$

Comment: okay thank you I am calculating my determinant wrong then

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct: the columns of that matrix form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ whenever the determinant is nonzero. This is true for most values of $k$ -- in fact, there is only one $k$ that *doesn't* work.

Comment: I got k-17 = detA

Comment: so k can not equal 17?

Comment: would this be correct?

Comment: @javahelper123 I think you computed the determinant incorrectly, but otherwise your reasoning is correct.

Comment: well the 2nd and 3rd columns are 0, and for the first column I got Matrix $A$  
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&3& 
\\0&1&4   
\\3&4&k 
\end{bmatrix}$ which gives k-19

Comment: and for the last column I got Matrix $A$  
$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0 
\\0&0&1   
\\2&3&4  
\end{bmatrix}$ which gives -2

Comment: sorry should it be k - 23?

Comment: Please try not to make so many short comments. You can also edit and delete your own comments. You should find that the determinant is $k-29$. (Hint: you can use row operations to make the bottom row into $0,0,0,k-29$.)

Comment: why am I using row operations shouldn't I just find the determinant of the 4x4 matrix?

Comment: That's just one way of finding the determinant (remember what row operations do to the determinant of a matrix?), but there is only one correct answer.

Comment: okay I finally got it thanks